# Reg: support to minimize query hitting more times

Tags: php, mysql

**Expected output**: Need to print 4 quarter wage_amt

```
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| wages_amt_q1 | wages_amt_q2 | wages_amt_q3 | wages_amt_q4 |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
| 108          | 100          | 18           | 128          |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**Current output**: Pull all jobs id from jobs table, Create loop pass each job id in the below query, execute 4 time to get 4 quarter values.

> select avg(wages) as wages_amt_q1 from wages where job_id = 73  and
>   date_id in (select date_id from wages_date where quarter = 1 and year
>   = 2015) group by job_id;

```
+--------------+
| wages_amt_q1 |
+--------------+
| 108          |
+--------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

do the need full support to minimize query hitting more times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get wages per quarter using the following query:

```
SELECT `wages_date`.`quarter`,`wages_date`.`year`,avg(`wages`.`wages`)
FROM `wages`
LEFT JOIN `wages_date` ON `wages_date`.`date_id`=`wages`.`date_id`
WHERE (`job_id` = 73)
GROUP BY `wages_date`.`quartner`,`wages_date`.`year`;
```

Comment: awesome ! 40 min changed to 10 min